# how to globalize passed in function variables python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

How would I globalize globalme1, 2 and 3 variables?

```
def example(globalme1, globalme2, globalme3=''):
       print("")
```

I tried globalizing them before the function.

globalize: Make accessible to other functions

Comment: What do you mean by "globalize"? Please explain in more detail what you expect this code to do.

Comment: if by 'globalize' you mean making the variables accessible in the outer scope: please don't try, use `return` values instead

Comment: A Python function *never* receives variables - it merely receives values.  Whether or not those values came from variables is not something the function should (or can!) care about.

Comment: @jasonharper I agee but these values arent not being used by other functions :(

Comment: @asdf101 return as in a return statement. Those are only allowed once in each function. Sorry im new to coding so

Comment: @GrandmaKisses they can occur multiple times in a function, it's just that the first one that is encountered exits the function. You can return multiple values at once: `return value1, value2, ... etc`, then use `values = example(arguments)` to get a tuple of the return values or `value1, value2, ... etc = example(arguments)` to automatically unpack them

Comment: Why would you want to use a global variable. In my many years of programming I have never needed a global variable.

Comment: @GrandmaKisses why is the answer no longer accepted? is something wrong?

Comment: @asdf101 I dont know I tried accepting the answer below and some how I ended up here lol. Not the best stackoverflow person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't, instead use return values:

```py
def example(argument1, argument2, argument3 = ""):
    print("")
    # do some things with your inputs
    return argument1, argument2, argument3
```

Then you can call the function like this to automatically unpack the function output:

```
value1 = "example"
value2 = 42
value3 = "yay, return values"

value1, value2, value3 = example(value1, value2, value3)
```

or like this to get a tuple:

```
values = example(value1, value2, value3)
```

see also [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil#19158418)